# How does Border image on CSS3 work?

Tags: css

I am reading about Border-Image on CSS3 but I don't understand how it slices the image. Anyone give me a explanation?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp The tutorial on W3C

Comment: Whatever this site is, so How ImageBorder works?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky to explain without graphics. I've done a few blog posts on the subject that may help:

- [Border-Image Explained](http://demosthenes.info/blog/438/CSS3-Border-Image-Explained)
- [An example that turns images into postage stamps using border-image](http://demosthenes.info/blog/446/Turn-Images-Into-Postage-Stamps-With-CSS3-borderimage)
- While this article doesn't deal with border-image in depth, it does note that [the drop-shadow filter will work on them directly](http://demosthenes.info/blog/598/boxshadow-property-vs-dropshadow-filter-a-complete-comparison)

I hope this helps!